# Accessing IP/WiFi CCTV camera using browser

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip, camera, cctv

OK, I have a CCTV camera that works either with cable or wifi, but my issue is that I know the IP address but when I input the address in a browser it comes back that it can't find.  I can use the manufactures software to access it fine.  I can arp -a and see both the network IP and the wifi IP.  My network is 192.xx and the wifi is 10.xx of the camera.

Is there a way to gain access to the cameras "router" interface as I want to change the SSID and IP address.

Comment: What make and model of camera? How are you routing between 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x (note that its 192.168 - 192.x is actually largely valid IP address space, but with routing issues for people who misconfigure stuff elsewhere in 192.x.x.x)

Comment: When connecting via WiFi the cameras DHCP settings would issue ips on 10.xx but when connecting through my router the router would give the cameras ip in the networks range in the 192.168.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have some kind of guest network / WIFI isolation configured on your router which will most likely be the root cause of your router.    Is there any reason not to turn WIFI isolation off and have the WIFI bridged onto your existing network, or - better yet - can you cable your cameras using ethernet - this is much better from a speed, security and reliability point of view.

Comment: I seem to think your missing the whole picture.  The camera has ethernet cable and WiFi antenna so you can communicate either way.  My issue is getting into the cameras communication settings to change the SSID and IP address.  Each time power is removed the cameras IP address will change, but using the wifi app will automatically get on the same wifi address the cameras DHCP outputs.

Comment: You said the camera was on the 10.x wifi network but your Ethernet network is on 192.  If your camera is cabled to both networks you need to find the cameras Ethernet interface in the 192 network and connect to that. Really though, you need to describe your network better because it makes no sense you can see the cameras in the 10.x network when thats not the same net as the lan - this would imply cameras are on a different network - which would seem from your post to be wifi, but then you would not need to change the said etc

Comment: Also, you have still not advised the make and model of the cameras.

Comment: Operating System:  Embedded LNUX  Operating system 
Supporting multiple protocols TCP/UDP/IP/HTTP/SMTP/DHCP/DDNS/UPNP/NTP/Onvif 
wifi: Support  80211B/G/N
System Interface   RJ45 interface   10/100M Adaptive

Comment: Shenzhen Factory  CCTV 720P HD WIFI P2P PTZ Wifi Surveillance Wireless IP Camera Outdoor

Comment: Thank you for that.  Can you clarify your network setup - ie can you confirm if the 192.168 network is your lan and the 10.x network is the WIFI.  Also, when you talk about ARP, are you referring to the MAC address of the camera or router or something else.

Comment: My network IP is 192.168.8.1 and the cameras DHCP keeps changing when power is removed but always comes up in 10.xx.  Last time I had looked via wifi it was 10.150.160.1

Comment: Based on what you have said, I'm pretty sure my initial assessment of the router isolating WIFI from LAN is correct.   If you are going to be playing with WIFI settings you really should connect the cameras to ethernet and access them on the ethernet address.  If thats not practical and you are willing to risk it, have you tried connecting your PC up to WIFI and accessing the web interface on the cameras through that?  (That would bypass the WIFI isolation because you will be in the same network as the cameras)